# How to create custom commands for Siri

Tags: swift, siri, sirikit

I need to create custom commands for sirikit. for example:

> schedule a meeting today 5 pm

my app should be able to schedule the meeting
another example:

> follow up with X tomorrow 7 PM

and so on.

Is there a way to integrate such custom commands with Siri? any keywords would be helpful, I just don't know where should I start my search.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use SiriKit to achieve this. Please see wwdc 2016 video
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/217/

Apple now introduced siri shortcuts but you can't take variable parameters from voice commands in siri shortcuts. It is just a shortcut to a particular action/activity. See wwdc 2018 video.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/211/

Comment: Thanks @bilal, I just finished watching the video and I understand that SiriKit support specific domains, but Calendar and Appointments is not one of listed domains. So is there a way to handle that? Is it possible to built using Lists and Notes domain since it takes date component !? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/lists_and_notes